# Derivative of $f(x)=\frac{7x^3+3x+30}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$f(x)=\frac{7x^3+3x+30}{\sqrt{x}}$$

$f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(7x^3+3x+30)-(21x^2+3)(\sqrt{x})}{(x^{1/2})^2}$

$f^{\prime}(x)=\dfrac{\dfrac{7x^3}{2\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{3x}{2\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{30}{2\sqrt{x}}-21x^{3/2}+3\sqrt{x}}{(x^{1/2})^2}$

Is this correct? It doesn't seem correct. How do I proceed from here? Please show steps. Thank you.

Comment: Try getting rid of that denominator! You've also dropped a minus sign in the final term of the numerator.

Comment: You also got the quotient rule backward (should be $u'v-v'u$ rather than $v'u-u'v$), and you lost a power of $x$ in the second-to-last term: $(21x^2)\sqrt{x} = 21x^{5/2},$ not $21x^{3/2}.$

Comment: @DavidK Ok, thanks, I didn't know that the order in the quotient rule matters...

Comment: I forget the order too if I haven't used the rule in a while, so I think of a simple problem such as $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1.$ The answer is either $1\cdot 1 - x\cdot 0 = 1$ or $x\cdot 0 - 1\cdot 1 = -1$, and it is clear which answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to divide out the numerator by the denominator and differentiate term by term:  $$f(x) = 7x^{5/2} + 3x^{1/2} + 30x^{-1/2},$$ so $$f'(x) = \frac{35}{2}x^{3/2} + \frac{3}{2}x^{-1/2} - 15x^{-3/2}.$$  Done.